# Carte Server web page render issue

Tags: browser

Recently we have upgraded our Pentaho Data Integration Installation from 7.1 to 8.2
We have also carte server installed on same machine which points to latest version of data integration.

Carte server can be accessed as http://localhost:8081

After upgrade when we access Carte server using http://machinename:8081, web page doesn't render the content properly in the browser.

Any suggestions regarding it?

Thank
Dhru